# ImportError: cannot import name 'x' from 'y'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, anaconda

```
(ldm) C:\WBC\latent-diffusion-main>python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a sunset behind a mountain range, vector image" --ddim_eta 1.0 --n_samples 1 --n_iter 1 --H 384 --W 1024 --scale 5.0
Loading model from models/ldm/text2img-large/model.ckpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 108, in <module>
    model = load_model_from_config(config, "models/ldm/text2img-large/model.ckpt")  # TODO: check path
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 19, in load_model_from_config
    model = instantiate_from_config(config.model)
  File "c:\wbc\latent-diffusion-main\ldm\util.py", line 78, in instantiate_from_config
    return get_obj_from_str(config["target"])(**config.get("params", dict()))
  File "c:\wbc\latent-diffusion-main\ldm\util.py", line 86, in get_obj_from_str
    return getattr(importlib.import_module(module, package=None), cls)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\wbc\latent-diffusion-main\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pytorch_lightning as pl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning import metrics  # noqa: E402
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\metrics\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.metrics.classification import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\metrics\classification\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.metrics.classification.accuracy import Accuracy  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\metrics\classification\accuracy.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.metrics.utils import deprecated_metrics, void
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\metrics\utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.utilities.data import get_num_classes as _get_num_classes
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_num_classes' from 'torchmetrics.utilities.data' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\data.py)
```

I can't run a latent diffusion neural network. I'm using anaconda and the environment that comes with the neural network. I think I'm doing everything right, but something goes wrong. If you know how to solve this problem, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: This issue is discussed in [NVIDIA's GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/issues/1113).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your error, it appears get_num_classes doesn't exist anymore. I verified this by looking that their [github](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/metrics) and [docs](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/references/utilities.html).

It was removed after this [commit](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/metrics/commit/c537c9b3e8e801772a7e5670ff273321ed26e77b).

Comment: Upgrade pytorch-lightning. I upgraded pytorch-lightning==1.4.4 to 1.5.10 with pip install pytorch-lightning==1.5.10 and solved "get_num_classes" problem.